# Trouble connecting to mysql server with FIREDAC (Delphi)

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe5, firedac

I am just starting out with Delphi XE5 development and am having A LOT of trouble trying to connect to my mySQL server.

Using the TFDConnection i currently get this error:

> > [FireDAC][Phys][MySQL]-314. Cannot load vendor library [libmysql or libmysqld.dll]. The system cannot find the file specified...

I have already read the docs on this issue and i have:

- Sourced the LIBMYSQL.DLL from a MySQL Server installation
- Placed it in the bin directory of XE5 AND referenced it in FDDrivers.ini

I have also noticed that when i view FireDAC Links in XE5 it has TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink grayed out...

I can connect to SQLlite servers fine.

Comment: Set `DriverName` to `'MySQL'`. Did you try to doubleclick on `TFDConnection` component?

Comment: Yes i have set the DriverName and tried double-clicking TFDConnection component.  No luck with that...

Comment: Error message has been updated, accidentally posted wrong one the first time.

Comment: Do you installed x86 or x64 libmysql.dll ? If x64, then you need x86.

Comment: @da-soft yes i installed x86 version.  Do you know what else it could be?

Comment: Did you check whether libmysql.dll resides in a folder defined by system variable PATH, or it resides in app's folder or did you specify it as VendorLib in .ini file? [see](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Connect_to_MySQL_Server_(FireDAC)), Windows client software paragraph.

Comment: It is in the XE5 bin directory (EXE Folder).  I have also added that folder to my environment path as well as added it to the .ini file...

.ini file has the following entry:
[MySQL]
BaseDriverID=MySQL
VendorLib='C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\bin\libmysql.dll'

Comment: This article on [Connect MySQL localhost do Delphi - FireDac](https://medium.com/@soonsantos/connect-mysql-localhost-to-delphi-using-firedac-d617fd99ab59) may help.

Answer (score 0):

> I have also noticed that when i view FireDAC Links in XE5 it has TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink grayed out...

That's because the device cannot connect directly to the mySQL database. From my understanding, you're supposed to create a DataSnap server which will act as your middle tier.  The DSServer will connect to the MySQL DB through FDConnection + FDQuery (note that the MySQL link will work here).

However, I am still stuck at connecting the mobile application to the DSServer.  If you've figured out more, please share